# How to? Digitally connect to projector with Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04?

Tags: video, hdmi, dvi, projector

I have two laptops which are exhibiting the same behavior (which is to say no behavior at all) when I attach either to my projector.  I have two available cable paths for testing, both yielding the same results.

Lenovo w530 (mini-display port --> DVI) Ubuntu 18.04

Lenovo x220 (display port --> DVI) Ubuntu 20.04

I have tried two different DVI cables (with an appropriate set of adapters for each set-up).  This is the same cable used to test the external monitors (well, one of the two is but neither work with the projector so I didn't haul the 15' garden hose of a cable in to test it as well).

If I attach any external monitor, I get the expected behavior:  There is a brief flicker and the second monitor appears in the Displays settings area.  By contrast, if I attach either laptop to my projector nothing happens to either.  There is no flicker (of recognition); there is no change in Displays; xrandr shows no changes.  Google was fruitless.

What do I need to do to make this work?

I was able to confirm this is a digital connection issue.  I cobbled together and tested a VGA solution and it behaved just like the monitor connections have.

EDIT:

I have included output from `sudo journalctl  --follow`:

Output from two separate laptops attempting to connect to an Optoma projector via a DVI cable.

This first one is running Ubuntu 18.04. I added the gap in the middle when I connected the cable with a mini-display port adapter. (There is likely superfluous output at the end as I was checking the projector and not looking at the output directly.):

Also, this first laptop is running a special driver (the second laptop is not).  Per Software and Updates:

```
Software & Updates
NVIDIA Corportation:  GK107GLM [Quadro K1000M]
This device is using an alternative driver.  
Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.108 from nvidia-340 (proprietary)
```

```
sudo journalctl --follow
-- Logs begin at Sun 2020-06-28 04:15:21 PDT. --
Dec 19 11:56:31 archer dbus-daemon[1795]: [session uid=1000 pid=1795] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Telepathy.AccountManager' unit='telepathy-mission-control-5.service' requested by ':1.89' (uid=1000 pid=2372 comm=&amp;quot;telepathy-indicator &amp;quot; label=&amp;quot;unconfined&amp;quot;)
Dec 19 11:56:31 archer systemd[1771]: Starting Telepathy Mission Control service...
Dec 19 11:56:31 archer dbus-daemon[1795]: [session uid=1000 pid=1795] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Telepathy.AccountManager'
Dec 19 11:56:31 archer systemd[1771]: Started Telepathy Mission Control service.
Dec 19 11:56:31 archer dbus-daemon[1795]: [session uid=1000 pid=1795] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Client.Vino' requested by ':1.90' (uid=1000 pid=2376 comm=&amp;quot;/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5 &amp;quot; label=&amp;quot;/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5 (enforce)&amp;quot;)
Dec 19 11:56:31 archer org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Client.Vino[1795]: Unknown option --tube
Dec 19 11:56:31 archer org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Client.Vino[1795]: Run 'vino-server --help' to see a full list of available command line options
Dec 19 11:56:31 archer dbus-daemon[1795]: [session uid=1000 pid=1795] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Client.Vino' failed: Process org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Client.Vino exited with status 1
Dec 19 11:56:34 archer sudo[2384]: jamesisin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/jamesisin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl --follow
Dec 19 11:56:34 archer sudo[2384]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 19 11:56:36 archer zeitgeist-daemon[2287]: [19:56:36.645847 WARNING] zeitgeist-daemon.vala:127: Unable to parse version info!
Dec 19 11:56:36 archer zeitgeist-datah[2386]: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:227: Unable to get name &amp;quot;org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub&amp;quot; on the bus!





Dec 19 11:56:47 archer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1789]: (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device DFP-1
Dec 19 11:56:47 archer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1789]: (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
Dec 19 11:56:47 archer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1789]: (**) NVIDIA(0):     device DFP-1 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
Dec 19 11:56:47 archer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1789]: (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
Dec 19 11:56:47 archer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1789]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode &amp;quot;DP-0: nvidia-auto-select @800x600 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=800x600, ViewPortOut=800x600+0+0}&amp;quot;
Dec 19 11:56:47 archer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1789]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode &amp;quot;NULL&amp;quot;
Dec 19 11:57:17 archer gnome-software[2408]: enabled plugins: systemd-updates, packagekit-url-to-app, packagekit-refresh, packagekit, fwupd, ubuntuone, packagekit-local, packagekit-refine-repos, os-release, shell-extensions, packagekit-proxy, packagekit-upgrade, packagekit-offline, desktop-categories, appstream, packagekit-refine, odrs, desktop-menu-path, steam, hardcoded-featured, generic-updates, modalias, rewrite-resource, hardcoded-popular, hardcoded-blacklist, packagekit-history, snap, provenance, provenance-license, icons, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
Dec 19 11:57:17 archer gnome-software[2408]: disabled plugins: dpkg, repos, dummy, epiphany
Dec 19 11:57:17 archer dbus-daemon[1058]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.fwupd' unit='fwupd.service' requested by ':1.122' (uid=1000 pid=2408 comm=&amp;quot;/usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service &amp;quot; label=&amp;quot;unconfined&amp;quot;)
Dec 19 11:57:17 archer systemd[1]: Starting Firmware update daemon...
Dec 19 11:57:18 archer fwupd[2430]: 19:57:18:0244 FuPluginUefi         kernel efivars support missing: /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
Dec 19 11:57:18 archer dbus-daemon[1058]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'
Dec 19 11:57:18 archer systemd[1]: Started Firmware update daemon.
Dec 19 11:57:18 archer PackageKit[1653]: get-updates transaction /14842_edddaebe from uid 1000 finished with success after 941ms
Dec 19 11:57:18 archer gnome-software[2408]: Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
Dec 19 11:57:19 archer PackageKit[1653]: resolve transaction /14843_ceaccbcd from uid 1000 finished with success after 516ms
Dec 19 11:57:19 archer gnome-shell[1931]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.93/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/software_update_available
Dec 19 11:57:19 archer gnome-shell[1931]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.93/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/livepatch
Dec 19 11:57:21 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14844_edbdddcd from uid 1000 finished with success after 1521ms
Dec 19 11:57:21 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14845_aabbecad from uid 1000 finished with success after 601ms
Dec 19 11:57:22 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14846_aecdeaca from uid 1000 finished with success after 557ms
Dec 19 11:57:23 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14847_daadbcbb from uid 1000 finished with success after 578ms
Dec 19 11:57:23 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14848_bebbedeb from uid 1000 finished with success after 555ms
Dec 19 11:57:24 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14849_bebedecc from uid 1000 finished with success after 556ms
Dec 19 11:57:24 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14850_dcbcadac from uid 1000 finished with success after 555ms
Dec 19 11:57:25 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14851_aabcdccd from uid 1000 finished with success after 556ms
Dec 19 11:57:25 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14852_aeebddde from uid 1000 finished with success after 554ms
Dec 19 11:57:26 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14853_eaaaedad from uid 1000 finished with success after 555ms
Dec 19 11:57:27 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14854_cdeaebad from uid 1000 finished with success after 573ms
Dec 19 11:57:27 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14855_eccdedce from uid 1000 finished with success after 557ms
Dec 19 11:57:28 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14856_adbaedec from uid 1000 finished with success after 560ms
Dec 19 11:57:28 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14857_adddedab from uid 1000 finished with success after 556ms
Dec 19 11:57:29 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14858_bedcdbda from uid 1000 finished with success after 570ms
Dec 19 11:57:30 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14859_eaeedccd from uid 1000 finished with success after 572ms
Dec 19 11:57:30 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14860_adbdabdb from uid 1000 finished with success after 578ms
Dec 19 11:57:31 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14861_dcbaaeea from uid 1000 finished with success after 579ms
Dec 19 11:57:31 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14862_dbeaabad from uid 1000 finished with success after 554ms
Dec 19 11:57:32 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14863_cacdbced from uid 1000 finished with success after 571ms
Dec 19 11:57:32 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14864_bedbdcbe from uid 1000 finished with success after 573ms
Dec 19 11:57:33 archer PackageKit[1653]: search-file transaction /14865_ebacceea from uid 1000 finished with success after 576ms
Dec 19 11:57:34 archer PackageKit[1653]: get-details transaction /14866_cdaadbda from uid 1000 finished with success after 524ms
Dec 19 11:57:34 archer gnome-software[2408]: Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
Dec 19 11:57:34 archer gnome-software[2408]: Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
Dec 19 11:57:36 archer gnome-software[2408]: Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
Dec 19 11:57:37 archer gnome-software[2408]: Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
Dec 19 11:57:37 archer gnome-software[2408]: Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
Dec 19 11:57:37 archer gnome-software[2408]: Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
Dec 19 11:57:37 archer gnome-software[2408]: Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
Dec 19 11:57:38 archer gnome-software[2408]: ignoring non-installed app GsApp: [0x7efcec10b820]
                                             kind:                desktop
                                             state:               available
                                             quirk:               provenance
                                             id:                  org.kde.marble
                                             unique-id:           system/package/ubuntu-bionic-universe/desktop/org.kde.marble/*
                                             scope:               system
                                             bundle-kind:         package
                                             kudos:               my-language|hi-dpi-icon
                                             kudo-percentage:     40
                                             name:                KDE Marble
                                             pixbuf:              0x7efcf01a4d80
                                             icon-kind:           stock
                                             icon-name:           marble
                                             icon-prefix:         /var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-bionic-universe
                                             icon-kind:           cached
                                             icon-name:           marble_marble.png
                                             icon-prefix:         /var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-bionic-universe
                                             icon-kind:           remote
                                             version:             4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1
                                             summary:             Navigation and Maps
                                             description:         Marble is a generic geographical map widget and framework for KDE applications. The Marble widget shows the earth as a sphere but does not require hardware acceleration.  A minimal set of geographical data is included, so it can be used without an internet connection.
                                             
                                             This package is part of the KDE education module.
                                             source-00:           marble
                                             source-id-00:        marble;4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1;amd64;ubuntu-bionic-universe
                                             url{homepage}:       http://edu.kde.org/
                                             license:             LicenseRef-free=https://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing
                                             license-is-free:     yes
                                             management-plugin:   packagekit
                                             origin:              ubuntu-bionic-universe
                                             origin-appstream:    ubuntu-bionic-universe
                                             reviews:             0
                                             provides:            0
                                             install-date:        1
                                             size-installed:      unknowable
                                             size-download:       181.4 kB
                                             category:            Education
                                             category:            Geoscience
                                             category:            Geography
                                             category:            Science
                                             category:            Maps
                                             {GnomeSoftware::Creator}: appstream
^C
```

This second one is running Ubuntu 20.04 (I added the gap in the middle when I connected the cable with a display port adapter):

```
sudo journalctl --follow 
-- Logs begin at Fri 2020-04-24 16:20:06 PDT. --
Dec 19 19:00:54 phoenix sudo[11767]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Dec 19 19:00:54 phoenix sudo[11801]: jamesisin : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/jamesisin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt autoremove
Dec 19 19:00:54 phoenix sudo[11801]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 19 19:00:55 phoenix sudo[11801]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Dec 19 19:00:55 phoenix sudo[11829]: jamesisin : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/jamesisin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt autoclean
Dec 19 19:00:55 phoenix sudo[11829]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 19 19:00:55 phoenix sudo[11829]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Dec 19 19:01:03 phoenix systemd[1]: zsysd.service: Succeeded.
Dec 19 19:01:25 phoenix sudo[12005]: jamesisin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/jamesisin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl --follow
Dec 19 19:01:25 phoenix sudo[12005]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)




Dec 19 19:01:35 phoenix kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: HDMI-A-1: EDID is invalid:
Dec 19 19:01:35 phoenix kernel:         [00] BAD  00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 3e 8d 48 33 ae 04 00 00
Dec 19 19:01:35 phoenix kernel:         [00] BAD  35 0f 01 03 80 00 00 78 0a 64 fe a4 59 4e a7 22
Dec 19 19:01:35 phoenix kernel:         [00] BAD  12 4b 50 af de 00 31 59 3b d9 45 59 61 59 81 80
Dec 19 19:01:35 phoenix kernel:         [00] BAD  01 01 01 01 01 01 2f 0d 50 f0 30 e0 25 10 10 70
Dec 19 19:01:35 phoenix kernel:         [00] BAD  68 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 ff 00 4f 38 31
Dec 19 19:01:35 phoenix kernel:         [00] BAD  47 35 35 33 41 31 31 39 38 0a 00 00 00 fc 00 4f
Dec 19 19:01:35 phoenix kernel:         [00] BAD  70 74 6f 6d 61 20 48 33 31 0a 20 20 00 00 00 fd
Dec 19 19:01:35 phoenix kernel:         [00] BAD  00 2b 55 10 45 11 00 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 a1 ff
^C
```

Comment: Look at the logs. Observe `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect the projector.

Comment: @waltinator I have posted output here:  http://jamesisin.com/a_high-tech_blech/index.php/2020/12/debugging/ .  Please let me know if that's helpful.  I added spaces where I connected the projector cable.  There's probably extra output at the end because I moved to the projector to ensure it was on the correct input setting (and thus stopped watching the output).  Also, if you spot anything that ought to be sanitized, please let me know.  Otherwise I will pull this post (or make it private) once you have a change to review the data.  Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the log contents from your link would fit in the post in which case it may be better to include it? (personally I wouldn't know a DVI cable from a python and can't really tell whether that output is illuminating, but there's a slight hint that an nvidia GPU is somehow involved? Is that possible?)

Comment: @Zanna Per your suggestion I have pulled the log data into this post.  I have also added some information relating to NVIDIA for one of the laptops (the other is not using an NVIDIA driver).  Maybe that's a useful clue for someone.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your projector is defective? As far as the operating system should be concerned, it's just an external monitor like any other.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix That seems unlikely as the projector works via VGA and via DVI using various players--and it's been in service here for a couple of decades.